# Enable MFA for social account in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I setup the Azure AD as identity provider for Azure B2C tenant (using custom policy). Is it possible to enable MFA on social account (Microsoft AD account in my scenario)?

I've tried this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/totp), but not working. It seems it is for azure b2c local account.

Comment: You can for sure enable MFA for any user. How they sign in doesn't matter. When you say "not working", what actually happens?

Comment: Here's the log I can find from application insights: 
        "HResult": "80131500",
        "Message": "Technical Profile with id \"AzureMfa-GetAvailableDevices\" in Policy id \"B2C_1A_signupsignin_TOTP\" of Tenant id \"--.onmicrosoft.com\": GetClaimsAsync method returned \"UserMessageIfServerError\" - \"Cannot use MFA service, please try again later.\"."

Comment: Hmm.. one potential explanation could be that a claim expected by that technical profile is not available when a user logs in with another IdP. You could check the App Insights traces for both a local user and federated user and compare what claims are available when reaching that step.

Comment: @juunas I tried another sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/main/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa, after verifying the SMS, it reported the error "AADB2C99002: This user does not exist and profile 'AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId' requires the user to have already been created". My identity provider registered in Azure AD is a multi-tenant app, guess this is why there's no account created in b2c tenant after Azure AD account is authenticated. So the phone number cannot be saved. Then this AADB2C99002 error occurs.

Comment: Our AD tenant (not the B2C) has already enabled MFA, so our accounts actually do have phone number/email/totp configured. I am wondering if the B2C authentication flow can read these information so that users do not need to enter phone number or configure authenticator app again